# What should i do so that a user of my social website can send own current location to another use of my social website?

Tags: web

i am making a social website.i know aboutrealtime googlemaps geolocation tracking with javascript.but how to send location to another user just like we do in whatsapp?i searched it on google but i didn't found proper answer.

Comment: Your question is very broad and hard to answer but check Geo-location in HTML5 may help you get started:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

Comment: bro i know how to use it.i can detect users current location.but if two users are using my website than how can one user send own current location to another user of my website?

Comment: Very broad question. For communicating between clients you would most likely need a server component to accept and deliver locations. That has obvious privacy implications.

Comment: jere bro please explain ur point briefly.

Comment: This isn't really the place to ask for tutorials or code outlines for entire website modules like you're describing because there are tons of ways you *could* implement this idea "correctly". Each would have pros and cons and choosing the best would depend on your goals and a lot more info than you've provided here. SO is here to help when you *already have code* that tries a specific method, *but can't figure out why it doesn't work.* It's more a place for fixing details. A more detailed version of this question *might* fit better on the software engineering stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually this is pretty straightforward: The location of user A needs to be transferred from his device, via his browser, to your webserver. From there, you need to send it out to user B. A cannot usually send directly to B as web browsers do not usually listen on network ports.

As a concrete example:  So, as you already know how to acquire GPS coordinates via JavaScript, your solution could be to grab the data in JS,  send it to the server via Ajax (in other words a simple POST request to some API you have to implement server side). If you wish to be able to scale, store it in some shared data store between your web servers. A simple elasticsearch would probably be fine, but if you already have a database running you might as well store it in your user table (though if you intend to scale into millions of users that is probably to be avoided).

Be sure to worry about security and privacy, especially if you intend to rollout your site in the EU...

Comment: It doesn't have to be AJAX. It can be any method of sending requests from client to server - such as web sockets, server sent events etc.

Comment: @mason: Yes, of course. No use guessing what his environment, capabilities etc. are, though... all of this is just academic anyway as we don't even know if this is a real question, homework or whatever.  :)